# Calculating XY in Model Builder using Calculate field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I'm trying to calculate the lat/long of a feature class in GCS NAD83.  The picture shows what goes below.

[image]

I can get it to work for distances and areas, but not a centroid.  What looks incorrect?

Comment: have you tested the answer provided by @Evil Genius in a standard field calculation (either directly on the table or via the GP tool)? Establish if the problem is confined to your model.

Answer (score 1):

As given in the second Python example for [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000), it should be `!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!` (use `.` not `@`).

`@` should be used for converting units on length/area attributes.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  The field is a Double.

Comment: Expand "didn't work." Was there an error, or did it simply not populate a value, etc..

Comment: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Calculate Field (4)).

Comment: Modelbuilder stops and errors out.

Comment: This works for calculating area:
!Shape.Area@Acres!

Comment: How large are your areas? That's not a syntax error, sounds more like topology/memory issues...

Comment: Not more than 10 acres for each feature.

Comment: how complex are the polygon boundaries? very large numbers of vertices may impact memory during processing. try selecting just one feature and performing the calculation, or generalise your features.

Comment: It has to be !Shape!.centroid.X

Comment: it's a point feature.